ImGui custom shader using vulkan
Im making gui in imgui, using example from official repository(example_glfw_vulkan), and i encountered a problem, that i cant apply shader to my popup`s background.
expected result
in this image you can see result that i need to achieve, i do know how to write shaders, but i dont know how to properly read them and use in imgui, i was searching internet and asking chatgpt, but i didnt find anywhere some reproducable example or even parts of code that can help me achieve this
#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui_impl_vulkan.h"
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>        
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

#ifdef IMGUI_IMPL_VULKAN_USE_VOLK
#define VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <volk.h>
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER >= 1900) && !defined(IMGUI_DISABLE_WIN32_FUNCTIONS)
#pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions")
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define APP_USE_VULKAN_DEBUG_REPORT
#endif

const char* vertex_shader_src = R"(
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    TexCoord = inTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(inPos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)";

const char* fragment_shader_blur_horizontal = R"(
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D screenTexture;
uniform float weight[9];
void main() {
    vec2 tex_offset = 1.0 / textureSize(screenTexture, 0);
    vec3 result = texture(screenTexture, TexCoord).rgb * weight[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i) {
        result += texture(screenTexture, TexCoord + vec2(tex_offset.x * i, 0.0)).rgb * weight[i];
        result += texture(screenTexture, TexCoord - vec2(tex_offset.x * i, 0.0)).rgb * weight[i];
    }
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
)";

const char* fragment_shader_blur_vertical = R"(
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D screenTexture;
uniform float weight[9];
void main() {
    vec2 tex_offset = 1.0 / textureSize(screenTexture, 0);
    vec3 result = texture(screenTexture, TexCoord).rgb * weight[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; ++i) {
        result += texture(screenTexture, TexCoord + vec2(0.0, tex_offset.y * i)).rgb * weight[i];
        result += texture(screenTexture, TexCoord - vec2(0.0, tex_offset.y * i)).rgb * weight[i];
    }
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
)";

static VkAllocationCallbacks* g_Allocator = nullptr;
static VkInstance               g_Instance = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkPhysicalDevice         g_PhysicalDevice = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkDevice                 g_Device = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static uint32_t                 g_QueueFamily = (uint32_t)-1;
static VkQueue                  g_Queue = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkDebugReportCallbackEXT g_DebugReport = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkPipelineCache          g_PipelineCache = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkDescriptorPool         g_DescriptorPool = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

static ImGui_ImplVulkanH_Window g_MainWindowData;
static int                      g_MinImageCount = 2;
static bool                     g_SwapChainRebuild = false;

// Blur-specific Vulkan resources
static VkRenderPass              g_BlurRenderPass = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkPipeline                g_BlurPipeline = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkPipelineLayout          g_BlurPipelineLayout = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkFramebuffer             g_BlurFramebuffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkDescriptorSet           g_BlurDescriptorSet = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkImageView               g_BlurImageView = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkImage                   g_BlurImage = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
static VkDeviceMemory            g_BlurImageMemory = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

static void glfw_error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLFW Error %d: %s\n", error, description);
}
static void check_vk_result(VkResult err)
{
    if (err == 0)
        return;
    fprintf(stderr, "[vulkan] Error: VkResult = %d\n", err);
    if (err < 0)
        abort();
}

#ifdef APP_USE_VULKAN_DEBUG_REPORT
static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debug_report(VkDebugReportFlagsEXT flags, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT objectType, uint64_t object, size_t location, int32_t messageCode, const char* pLayerPrefix, const char* pMessage, void* pUserData)
{
    (void)flags; (void)object; (void)location; (void)messageCode; (void)pUserData; (void)pLayerPrefix;
    fprintf(stderr, "[vulkan] Debug report from ObjectType: %i\nMessage: %s\n\n", objectType, pMessage);
    return VK_FALSE;
}
#endif

static bool IsExtensionAvailable(const ImVector<VkExtensionProperties>& properties, const char* extension)
{
    for (const VkExtensionProperties& p : properties)
        if (strcmp(p.extensionName, extension) == 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}

static VkPhysicalDevice SetupVulkan_SelectPhysicalDevice()
{
    uint32_t gpu_count;
    VkResult err = vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(g_Instance, &gpu_count, nullptr);
    check_vk_result(err);
    IM_ASSERT(gpu_count > 0);

    ImVector<VkPhysicalDevice> gpus;
    gpus.resize(gpu_count);
    err = vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(g_Instance, &gpu_count, gpus.Data);
    check_vk_result(err);

    for (VkPhysicalDevice& device : gpus)
    {
        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties properties;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(device, &properties);
        if (properties.deviceType == VK_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_DISCRETE_GPU)
            return device;
    }

    if (gpu_count > 0)
        return gpus[0];
    return VK_NULL_HANDLE;
}

static void SetupVulkan(ImVector<const char*> instance_extensions)
{
    VkResult err;
#ifdef IMGUI_IMPL_VULKAN_USE_VOLK
    volkInitialize();
#endif

    {
        VkInstanceCreateInfo create_info = {};
        create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;

        uint32_t properties_count;
        ImVector<VkExtensionProperties> properties;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &properties_count, nullptr);
        properties.resize(properties_count);
        err = vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &properties_count, properties.Data);
        check_vk_result(err);

        if (IsExtensionAvailable(properties, VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME))
            instance_extensions.push_back(VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME);
#ifdef VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME
        if (IsExtensionAvailable(properties, VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME))
        {
            instance_extensions.push_back(VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME);
            create_info.flags |= VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
        }
#endif

#ifdef APP_USE_VULKAN_DEBUG_REPORT
        const char* layers[] = { "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" };
        create_info.enabledLayerCount = 1;
        create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = layers;
        instance_extensions.push_back("VK_EXT_debug_report");
#endif

        create_info.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t)instance_extensions.Size;
        create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = instance_extensions.Data;
        err = vkCreateInstance(&create_info, g_Allocator, &g_Instance);
        check_vk_result(err);
#ifdef IMGUI_IMPL_VULKAN_USE_VOLK
        volkLoadInstance(g_Instance);
#endif

#ifdef APP_USE_VULKAN_DEBUG_REPORT
        auto f_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(g_Instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
        IM_ASSERT(f_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT != nullptr);
        VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT debug_report_ci = {};
        debug_report_ci.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_REPORT_CALLBACK_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
        debug_report_ci.flags = VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_REPORT_PERFORMANCE_WARNING_BIT_EXT;
        debug_report_ci.pfnCallback = debug_report;
        debug_report_ci.pUserData = nullptr;
        err = f_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT(g_Instance, &debug_report_ci, g_Allocator, &g_DebugReport);
        check_vk_result(err);
#endif
    }

    g_PhysicalDevice = SetupVulkan_SelectPhysicalDevice();

    {
        VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures device_features = {};
        device_features.samplerAnisotropy = VK_TRUE;
        device_features.sampleRateShading = VK_TRUE;
        device_features.fragmentStoresAndAtomics = VK_TRUE;

        VkDeviceCreateInfo create_info = {};
        create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
        create_info.pEnabledFeatures = &device_features;
        create_info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
        VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo queue_create_info = {};
        queue_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
        queue_create_info.queueFamilyIndex = 0;
        queue_create_info.queueCount = 1;
        float queue_priority = 1.0f;
        queue_create_info.pQueuePriorities = &queue_priority;
        create_info.pQueueCreateInfos = &queue_create_info;
        create_info.enabledExtensionCount = 1;
        const char* device_extensions[] = { VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME };
        create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = device_extensions;
        err = vkCreateDevice(g_PhysicalDevice, &create_info, g_Allocator, &g_Device);
        check_vk_result(err);

        vkGetDeviceQueue(g_Device, 0, 0, &g_Queue);
    }
}

static void CleanupVulkan()
{
    vkDestroyPipeline(g_Device, g_BlurPipeline, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyPipelineLayout(g_Device, g_BlurPipelineLayout, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyRenderPass(g_Device, g_BlurRenderPass, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyFramebuffer(g_Device, g_BlurFramebuffer, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyImageView(g_Device, g_BlurImageView, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyImage(g_Device, g_BlurImage, g_Allocator);
    vkFreeMemory(g_Device, g_BlurImageMemory, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyDescriptorPool(g_Device, g_DescriptorPool, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyDevice(g_Device, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyInstance(g_Instance, g_Allocator);
}

static void SetupBlurResources()
{
    VkResult err;

    VkImageCreateInfo image_create_info = {};
    image_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    image_create_info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    image_create_info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    image_create_info.extent.width = 800;
    image_create_info.extent.height = 600; 
    image_create_info.extent.depth = 1;
    image_create_info.mipLevels = 1;
    image_create_info.arrayLayers = 1;
    image_create_info.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    image_create_info.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    image_create_info.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
    image_create_info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    image_create_info.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;

    err = vkCreateImage(g_Device, &image_create_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurImage);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkMemoryRequirements mem_req;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(g_Device, g_BlurImage, &mem_req);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo mem_alloc_info = {};
    mem_alloc_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    mem_alloc_info.allocationSize = mem_req.size;
    mem_alloc_info.memoryTypeIndex = 0;
    err = vkAllocateMemory(g_Device, &mem_alloc_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurImageMemory);
    check_vk_result(err);

    err = vkBindImageMemory(g_Device, g_BlurImage, g_BlurImageMemory, 0);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkImageViewCreateInfo image_view_create_info = {};
    image_view_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    image_view_create_info.image = g_BlurImage;
    image_view_create_info.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    image_view_create_info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    image_view_create_info.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
    image_view_create_info.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
    image_view_create_info.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
    image_view_create_info.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY;
    image_view_create_info.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    image_view_create_info.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    image_view_create_info.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    image_view_create_info.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    image_view_create_info.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    err = vkCreateImageView(g_Device, &image_view_create_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurImageView);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkFramebufferCreateInfo framebuffer_create_info = {};
    framebuffer_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    framebuffer_create_info.renderPass = g_BlurRenderPass;
    framebuffer_create_info.attachmentCount = 1;
    framebuffer_create_info.pAttachments = &g_BlurImageView;
    framebuffer_create_info.width = 800; 
    framebuffer_create_info.height = 600; 
    framebuffer_create_info.layers = 1;

    err = vkCreateFramebuffer(g_Device, &framebuffer_create_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurFramebuffer);
    check_vk_result(err);
}

static void SetupBlurRenderPass()
{
    VkResult err;

    VkAttachmentDescription color_attachment = {};
    color_attachment.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    color_attachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    color_attachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    color_attachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    color_attachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_attachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    color_attachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    color_attachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

    VkAttachmentReference color_attachment_ref = {};
    color_attachment_ref.attachment = 0;
    color_attachment_ref.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &color_attachment_ref;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo render_pass_info = {};
    render_pass_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    render_pass_info.attachmentCount = 1;
    render_pass_info.pAttachments = &color_attachment;
    render_pass_info.subpassCount = 1;
    render_pass_info.pSubpasses = &subpass;

    err = vkCreateRenderPass(g_Device, &render_pass_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurRenderPass);
    check_vk_result(err);
}

static void SetupBlurPipeline()
{
    VkResult err;

    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo vert_shader_info = {};
    vert_shader_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    vert_shader_info.codeSize = sizeof(vertex_shader_src);
    vert_shader_info.pCode = (const uint32_t*)vertex_shader_src;
    VkShaderModule vert_shader_module;
    err = vkCreateShaderModule(g_Device, &vert_shader_info, g_Allocator, &vert_shader_module);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo frag_shader_info = {};
    frag_shader_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    frag_shader_info.codeSize = sizeof(fragment_shader_blur_horizontal);
    frag_shader_info.pCode = (const uint32_t*)fragment_shader_blur_horizontal;
    VkShaderModule frag_shader_module;
    err = vkCreateShaderModule(g_Device, &frag_shader_info, g_Allocator, &frag_shader_module);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo vert_shader_stage_info = {};
    vert_shader_stage_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    vert_shader_stage_info.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    vert_shader_stage_info.module = vert_shader_module;
    vert_shader_stage_info.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo frag_shader_stage_info = {};
    frag_shader_stage_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    frag_shader_stage_info.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    frag_shader_stage_info.module = frag_shader_module;
    frag_shader_stage_info.pName = "main";

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo shader_stages[] = { vert_shader_stage_info, frag_shader_stage_info };

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertex_input_info = {};
    vertex_input_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo input_assembly = {};
    input_assembly.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    input_assembly.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewport_state = {};
    viewport_state.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    viewport_state.viewportCount = 1;
    viewport_state.scissorCount = 1;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizer = {};
    rasterizer.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    rasterizer.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    rasterizer.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    rasterizer.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    rasterizer.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampling = {};
    multisampling.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    multisampling.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState color_blend_attachment = {};
    color_blend_attachment.blendEnable = VK_FALSE;
    color_blend_attachment.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo color_blending = {};
    color_blending.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    color_blending.attachmentCount = 1;
    color_blending.pAttachments = &color_blend_attachment;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipeline_layout_info = {};
    pipeline_layout_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipeline_layout_info.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;

    err = vkCreatePipelineLayout(g_Device, &pipeline_layout_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurPipelineLayout);
    check_vk_result(err);

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipeline_info = {};
    pipeline_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipeline_info.stageCount = 2;
    pipeline_info.pStages = shader_stages;
    pipeline_info.pVertexInputState = &vertex_input_info;
    pipeline_info.pInputAssemblyState = &input_assembly;
    pipeline_info.pViewportState = &viewport_state;
    pipeline_info.pRasterizationState = &rasterizer;
    pipeline_info.pMultisampleState = &multisampling;
    pipeline_info.pColorBlendState = &color_blending;
    pipeline_info.pDepthStencilState = nullptr;
    pipeline_info.pDynamicState = nullptr;
    pipeline_info.layout = g_BlurPipelineLayout;
    pipeline_info.renderPass = g_BlurRenderPass;
    pipeline_info.subpass = 0;

    err = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(g_Device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipeline_info, g_Allocator, &g_BlurPipeline);
    check_vk_result(err);

    vkDestroyShaderModule(g_Device, frag_shader_module, g_Allocator);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(g_Device, vert_shader_module, g_Allocator);
}

static void ApplyBlurToPopupBackground()
{
    // ??
}

int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
    if (!glfwVulkanSupported())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Vulkan not supported\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "ImGui Vulkan Example", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr)
        return -1;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    ImVector<const char*> instance_extensions;
    instance_extensions.push_back(VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME);
    SetupVulkan(instance_extensions);
    SetupBlurResources();
    SetupBlurRenderPass();
    SetupBlurPipeline();

    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForVulkan(window, true);

    ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo init_info = {};
    init_info.Instance = g_Instance;
    init_info.PhysicalDevice = g_PhysicalDevice;
    init_info.Device = g_Device;
    init_info.QueueFamily = g_QueueFamily;
    init_info.Queue = g_Queue;
    init_info.PipelineCache = g_PipelineCache;
    init_info.DescriptorPool = g_DescriptorPool;
    init_info.Allocator = g_Allocator;
    init_info.CheckVkResultFn = check_vk_result;

    ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(&init_info);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        ImGui_ImplVulkan_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        if (ImGui::BeginPopup("Popup"))
        {
            ApplyBlurToPopupBackground();
            ImGui::Text("This is a popup with blur effect!");
            ImGui::EndPopup();
        }

        ImGui::Render();

        ApplyBlurToPopupBackground();

    }

    CleanupVulkan();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

in my code there is missing function to apply blur, and i dont even know if i'm proccesing shaders correctly
